# Android Eclipse Camera act's different with different debuggers

Tags: android, camera

I have this application that takes a picture and then saves it to the database.
I'm using xperia z5 compact as a debugger.

It does not come to saving the picture, It only wants to retake the picture all the time. Sometimes it works but rarely.

When I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3 it works

I have this in my manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"     
android:required="false"></uses-feature>
```

Here's my camera code:

```
public class Camera extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

ImageButton ib;
Button b;
ImageView iv;
Intent i;
final static int cameraData = 0;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
Bitmap bmp;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photo);

    initialize();
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    super.onResume();
    startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);



}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{    
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }
}


private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivReturnedPic);
    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibTakePic);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSetWall);
    b.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    ib.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.bSetWall:
        createImageFromBitmap(bmp);
        Intent visaData = new Intent (Camera.this, AddKvitto.class);
        startActivity(visaData);
        break;
    case R.id.ibTakePic:
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
        break;

    }
}
public String createImageFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String fileName = "myImage";//no .png or .jpg needed
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        // remember close file output
        fo.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fileName = null;
    }
    return fileName;
}


}
```